# QQmlImageProvider for progressive JPEG loading

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qimage

Is there any interconnection between `QQmlImageProvider` and ability to gradually load JPEG files into `Image` view?

Say, given a `GridView` with a bunch of JPEGs. All of them just are small previews, and hence at the first glance they can be 1 / 16 of full quality disposable.

Is it possible to use some mechanism to load just first block of JPEGs to draw a low-resolution previews, and only later to load full-quality images in background (one-by-one or using some `QtConcurrent` mechanism in parallel)?

Comment: I don't think there is any ready to use Qt Imageproviders for that. You also need your images to be in the right format and include for example 8-bit preview image in header. you then need to load and parse images yourself, extract preview from header, return it to QML as pixamp or QImage, and after you have loaded whole source of your image update the image in QML.

Comment: @Xplatforms The big question is who is responsible to emit an event "high resolution is ready" when high-resolution version is completely loaded.

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#status-prop

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you

Comment: also this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#progress-prop